# How to convert a bitmap to an image resource - Android

Tags: android

I am trying to set an image to a custom View, but my problem is that this custom view only accept the `setImageResource()` method.

My image files are stored locally inside the phone, so I use a code to encode them to bitmap.

Can I use the `setImageResource()` function to display bitmap images in some way?

Answer (score 0):

No, sorry. The custom view would need to be modified to support other image sources.

Answer (score 0):

For the custom view you need to modify the support, once you have do it, then
If it is encoded on Base64, you can transform that content to a image

```
val decodedString = Base64.decode(document.thumbnailImage, Base64.DEFAULT)
val decodedByte = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(decodedString, 0, decodedString.size)
imageView.setImageBitmap(decodedByte)
```